# Selection of a flow meter for water injection facility

Tags: instrumentation

There are 4 water injection pumps which supply water to injection wells. The requirement is to install one common flow meter on the common pumps discharge header and one flow meter per each suction line of each pump (total 5 meters). The constraint here is regarding the straight run requirements, especially on the individual pump suction.

•   Pump common suction header will be laid outside the pump house and 20” in dia.

•   Individual pump suction piping, line size is 12” and available straight piping length is approximately 4300mm (including meter run). what is the suitable flow meter type with lesser straight run requirement to fit to our piping layout. Also note that this piping will be elevated and need scaffold to access the meter.

Comment: Your range of flow rate is also important, and possibly accuracy requirement. The flow rate is needed in addition to diameter to quantify entrance length effects, which are probably going to be an issue. Depending on the numbers, you may have to resort to tricks like flow straighteners / conditioners, and/or in situ calibration. Also this is a good question for a salesperson at a large company selling the instrumentation (but be sure to pick one that sells multiple technologies). They are paid to give guidance in such situations.